# discord.py limiting a command to only be a slash command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a command that is only a slash command however my bot uses hybrid commands and normal prefix commands and Im not sure how to make it just a slash command.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower() == ";report" or message.content.lower() == ";suggest":
        return
    await client.process_commands(message)
    
@client.hybrid_command(name = "report", with_app_command=True, description="Make a suggestion to the bot or report an issue", aliases=["suggest"])
@commands.guild_only()
async def report(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_modal(my_modal())
```

I tried making an on_message event that ignores the prefix command but it ignores the on_message and listens to the command. I've tried @tree.command and @client.slash_command but they don't work.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, It is just @client.tree.command for me but it depends on what you put in the `commands.Bot` section of your code. most people it's either client or bot

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).